# how to merge 2nd array in 1'st array in php

Tags: php, arrays

what i need

- i need to merge two arrays with 2nd array into 1'st array within same index.

array output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [RESPONSE] => 2
        [RESPONSE_TEXT] => 
        [DEVELOPER_TEXT] => 
        [RESPONSE_DATE_TIME] => 14-FEB-2017 11:09
        [RESPONSE_DATE] => 2017-02-14 11:09:52
        [RESPONSE_BY_ID] => 84
        [RESPONSE_ASSIGNED_USER_NAME] => bb
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [RESPONSE] => 1
        [RESPONSE_TEXT] => 
        [DEVELOPER_TEXT] => 
        [RESPONSE_DATE_TIME] => 16-JAN-2017 14:07
        [RESPONSE_DATE] => 2017-01-16 14:07:47
        [RESPONSE_BY_ID] => 1
        [RESPONSE_ASSIGNED_USER_NAME] => aaa
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [RESPONSE] => 3
        [RESPONSE_TEXT] => 
        [DEVELOPER_TEXT] => 
        [RESPONSE_DATE_TIME] => 16-JAN-2017 14:02
        [RESPONSE_DATE] => 2017-01-16 14:02:01
        [RESPONSE_BY_ID] => 1
        [RESPONSE_ASSIGNED_USER_NAME] => cc
    )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [RESPONSE_USER_NAME] => my name
    )

  )
```

php code

```
   print_r(array_merge(array_values($result1), array_values($result2)));
```

o/p of above php code

```
    Array
   (

   [0] => Array
   (
    [RESPONSE] => 2
    [RESPONSE_TEXT] => 
    [DEVELOPER_TEXT] => 
    [RESPONSE_DATE_TIME] => 14-FEB-2017 11:09
    [RESPONSE_DATE] => 2017-02-14 11:09:52
    [RESPONSE_BY_ID] => 84
    [RESPONSE_ASSIGNED_USER_NAME] => bb
   )
   [1] => Array
    (
        [RESPONSE_USER_NAME] => my name
    )

   )
```

- i need output like

  ```
     Array
       (
          [0] => Array
        (
      [RESPONSE] => 2
      [RESPONSE_TEXT] => 
      [DEVELOPER_TEXT] => 
      [RESPONSE_DATE_TIME] => 14-FEB-2017 11:09
      [RESPONSE_DATE] => 2017-02-14 11:09:52
      [RESPONSE_BY_ID] => 84
      [RESPONSE_ASSIGNED_USER_NAME] => bb
      [RESPONSE_USER_NAME] => my name
        )

      [1] => Array
     (
      [RESPONSE] => 1
      [RESPONSE_TEXT] => 
      [DEVELOPER_TEXT] => 
      [RESPONSE_DATE_TIME] => 16-JAN-2017 14:07
      [RESPONSE_DATE] => 2017-01-16 14:07:47
      [RESPONSE_BY_ID] => 1
      [RESPONSE_ASSIGNED_USER_NAME] => aa
      [RESPONSE_USER_NAME] => my name
      )
  ```

problem

- i have tried array_merge php function buts its appending in 1'st array with another array index.
- please suggest the solution for this problem

Comment: print_r(array_push(array_values($result1), array_values($result2)));

Comment: What about `array1 + array2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are looking for something like that ?

```
  <?php 
$array1=Array
(
Array
    (
        'RESPONSE' => 2,
        'RESPONSE_TEXT' =>'' ,
        'DEVELOPER_TEXT' => '',
        'RESPONSE_DATE_TIME' => "14-FEB-2017 11:09",
        'RESPONSE_DATE' => "2017-02-14 11:09:52",
        'RESPONSE_BY_ID' => 84,
        'RESPONSE_ASSIGNED_USER_NAME' => "bb"
    ),

Array
    (
        'RESPONSE' => 2,
        'RESPONSE_TEXT' =>'' ,
        'DEVELOPER_TEXT' => '',
        'RESPONSE_DATE_TIME' => "14-FEB-2017 11:09",
        'RESPONSE_DATE' => "2017-02-14 11:09:52",
        'RESPONSE_BY_ID' => 5,
        'RESPONSE_ASSIGNED_USER_NAME' => "cc"
    ),

Array
    (
       'RESPONSE' => 2,
        'RESPONSE_TEXT' =>'' ,
        'DEVELOPER_TEXT' => '',
        'RESPONSE_DATE_TIME' => "14-FEB-2017 11:09",
        'RESPONSE_DATE' => "2017-02-14 11:09:52",
        'RESPONSE_BY_ID' => 6,
        'RESPONSE_ASSIGNED_USER_NAME' => "ee"
    )

);

$array2=Array
(
Array
    (
        'RESPONSE_USER_NAME' => "my name"
    )

  );

$final_array=[];
  foreach($array1 as $key =>$value){
      foreach($array2 as $key1=>$value2){

          $value=array_merge($value, $value2);

      }
      $final_array[]=$value;

  }
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($final_array);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [RESPONSE] => 2
            [RESPONSE_TEXT] => 
            [DEVELOPER_TEXT] => 
            [RESPONSE_DATE_TIME] => 14-FEB-2017 11:09
            [RESPONSE_DATE] => 2017-02-14 11:09:52
            [RESPONSE_BY_ID] => 84
            [RESPONSE_ASSIGNED_USER_NAME] => bb
            [RESPONSE_USER_NAME] => my name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [RESPONSE] => 2
            [RESPONSE_TEXT] => 
            [DEVELOPER_TEXT] => 
            [RESPONSE_DATE_TIME] => 14-FEB-2017 11:09
            [RESPONSE_DATE] => 2017-02-14 11:09:52
            [RESPONSE_BY_ID] => 5
            [RESPONSE_ASSIGNED_USER_NAME] => cc
            [RESPONSE_USER_NAME] => my name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [RESPONSE] => 2
            [RESPONSE_TEXT] => 
            [DEVELOPER_TEXT] => 
            [RESPONSE_DATE_TIME] => 14-FEB-2017 11:09
            [RESPONSE_DATE] => 2017-02-14 11:09:52
            [RESPONSE_BY_ID] => 6
            [RESPONSE_ASSIGNED_USER_NAME] => ee
            [RESPONSE_USER_NAME] => my name
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you don't want to merge. What you want is to merge each array in an array with an array in another array.
just do something like:

```
foreach ($result1 as $array){
   array_merge($array, $result[0])
}
```

Comment: Are you serious to answer this question?

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu why not ? It is indeed not the best question and not totaly clear, but it is a valid question in SO terms. It stateds input, desired output and what he has tried.

Comment: Okay Man... but I don't find a solution with loop fit.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu that could be, but i think this is because the question is not clear. That's why I stated it looks like, he want to do this. I kind of guess this out of the input and expected output, but feel free to submit a better answer, and correct me if needed. I always love to learn a better way, but i think it is more a matter of the question in this case ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($result1 as $key=>$array){
   array_merge($array, $result[$key])
}
```